# how to use the lib shp-write in a vue js application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to use this js function in my vue application but when I try to import this js library with `require('shp-write');`
It doesn't work.

I'm following this [example](https://github.com/mapbox/shp-write)

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you facing? And how did you link to it? Installed through npm or a direct <script> tag?